# Get unique ID or checksum to detect tampering of parent application process

Tags: c#, .net, security

How do you calculate a checksum for the parent application EXE for tamper detection?

Is it as simple as loading the EXE into memory and running a CRC32 on it? Is there a better way or an inbuilt mechanism that generates a unique ID per built/version of the EXE so you can detect if its been tampered or if the module is not executing in the original parent process it was compiled for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CodeAccessPermission` and Permissions Demands:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e879fzy.aspx

The `Demand()` method throws a `SecurityException` exception

> at run time if all callers higher in the call stack
>   have not been granted the permission specified by the current instance.

Also, you need to read up on code signing:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325833/Basics-of-Signing-and-Verifying-code

Here's an example of how to check an assembly's signature:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx

Sign the parent assembly. Give the child assembly's the parent assembly's public key. IF the parent assembly is signed with the correct public key, you're good. If not, fail.